# Need to specify type of an overloaded function using property of an interface

Tags: typescript, function, interface, overloading

I need to specify type of a function using property of an interface (in general need to define module's API using interface), but ts complains about returned type, seem like it takes into account only one type definition because complains about incorrect return type:

```
export interface DateWrapper {
    isSame(firstDate: DateType, secondDate: DateType): boolean;
    isSame(firstDate: DateType): (secondDate: DateType) => boolean;
}

export const isSame: DateWrapper['isSame'] = (
    firstDate: DateType,
    secondDate?: DateType,
) => {
    if (!secondDate) {
        return (secondDate_: DateType) =>
          areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate_);
    }

    return areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate);
};
```

and here is an error from ts:

```
Type 'boolean | ((secondDate_: DateType) => boolean)' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

Using `function declaration` to specify overload fixes the issue but I need to use **property of interface**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the solution that covers my case, maybe it would be useful for someone else:

```
export interface DateWrapper {
   isSame: typeof isSame;
}

export function isSame (firstDate: DateType, secondDate: DateType): boolean
export function isSame (firstDate: DateType): (secondDate: DateType) => boolean;
export function isSame (firstDate: DateType, secondDate?: DateType) {
    if (!secondDate) {
        return (secondDate_: DateType) => areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate_);
    }

    return areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a clean way to specify overloads for an arrow function *with different return types*.  There are plenty of examples on SO where either the return types are the same, or *any* is in the function for the returned value.  Given that, here are three less than optimal suggestions that vary in neatness and their preservation of type correctness.

Just use a type assertion.  The drawback here is that if the definition of *DateWrapper.isSame* changes then an error will be introduced.  In general its best to avoid type assertions if you can.

```
export const isSame = ((firstDate: DateType, secondDate?: DateType) => 
  (secondDate == null) 
    ? (secondDate_: DateType) => areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate_)
    : areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate)
) as DateWrapper['isSame'];
```

An alternative is to declare the overloaded function and assign it to variable.  Unlike the first solution, if the definition of *DateWrapper.isSame* changes, then you won't be able to build until these functions are refactored to match. The drawback is that this function exists in some scope and may cause confusion.

```
function isSameFn(firstDate: DateType, secondDate: DateType): boolean;
function isSameFn(firstDate: DateType): (secondDate: DateType) => boolean;
function isSameFn(firstDate: DateType, secondDate?: DateType) {
  return (secondDate == null) 
    ? (secondDate_: DateType) => areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate_)
    : areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate);
}
export const isSame: DateWrapper['isSame'] = isSameFn;
```

Two avoid polluting some scope, you can wrap the functions in an auto-executing function that returns the *isSame* function.  While this is the ugliest, it doesn't have any of the problems of the prior solutions.

```
export const isSame: DateWrapper['isSame'] = (() => {
  function isSameFn(firstDate: DateType, secondDate: DateType): boolean
  function isSameFn(firstDate: DateType): (secondDate: DateType) => boolean
  function isSameFn(firstDate: DateType, secondDate?: DateType) {
    return (secondDate == null) 
      ? (secondDate_: DateType) => areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate_)
      : areDatesEqueal(firstDate, secondDate);
  }
  return isSameFn;
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of suggest solutions suits me, drawback of the first one you described well regarding second one it looks like overhead for my case. And unfortunately you are right seems like there is no "clear" way to achieve the goal.

Thanks for detailed explanation!